# Differential Geometry Regular Surface problem

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove that a set $S\subset \mathbb R^3$ is a regular surface if and only if each of its points has a neighborhood in $S$ that is diffeomorphic to the disk $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2 + y^2 < 1\} $,

**Proof:** By Hypothesis, S is a regular surface. Then each of it points has a neighborhood that is diffeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb R^2$. To finish the proof we need to define a surface patch $\sigma: U \subset \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow V \subset S \subset \mathbb R^3 $. Let $U = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2|x^2+y^2 <1\}. $ Our diffeomorphism $\sigma$ then takes the form $\sigma(x,y)= (x,y,x^2+y^2)$ ,  $(x,y) \in U$. Hence the $\rightarrow $ part of the proof is finished.

Conversely, Suppose that each point of $S \subset \mathbb R^3$ has a neighborhood diffeomorphic to the disk$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2 + y^2 < 1\} $. We need to show that $S $ is a regular surface.

I'm lost trying to prove the second part of the proof. I'm thinking that I already have a diffeomorphism by hypothesis then I just need to show that this diffeomorphism satisfies the definition of a regular surface. Would that be the correct approach?

Also, is the first part of the proof satisfactory?

Any suggestions and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Text is Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by Christopher Tapp.

Comment: Do you have a particular surface? I didn't think so, but your $\sigma$ is parametrizing a piece of a paraboloid. ... The converse is immediate, as a disk in the plane is *an* open set in $\Bbb R^2$. But the direction that's trickier is the first direction. Here's a hint: Any open set in $\Bbb R^2$ contains a disk, and any disk is diffeomorphic to  $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2<1\}$ (why?).

Comment: any disk is diffeomorphic to the {(x,y): x^2 + y^2 < 1} since it's just a collection of open disks of radius 1 centered at the origin? You're going from an open set which contains disks of radius r in R^2 to disks of radius 1 centered at the origin?

Comment: Any open set is a collection of open disks. You should be able to write down a specific diffeomorphism from $B(0,1)$ (the unit ball centered at $0$) to $B(a,r)$ (the ball of radius $r$ centered at an arbitrary point $a$).

Comment: Suppose you are given a set $S$ which you don't know in advance that is a  regular surface. What does it mean that a point $p \in S$ has a neighborhood which is **diffeomorphic** to an open disc?